# Как в css сделать высокий шрифт?

Tags: html, css, jinja2

я делаю дизайн для сайта и там мне нужно сделать шрифт который растянут вверх. Пробовал свойство font-stretch: inherit, в яндексе допустим не работает. Другого решения не нашел. Надеюсь поможете :) спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, что правильно понял вопрос, но нужно что-то типа этого?

Можно просто растянуть блок с текстом с помощью свойства `transform` и функции `scale`:

```css
div {
  margin-top: 3rem;
  font-size: 72px;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  transform: scaleY(3);
}
```

```html
<div>Sample text</div>
```

Comment: спасибо! помогли